# Lagrange multiplier question with unit circle constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having trouble with the following question:

> Show $|ax + by| \leq (a^{2} + b^{2})^{1/2}$ if $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ by finding the maximum and minimum values of $f(x, y) = ax + by$ on the unit circle.

I'm learning multivariable calculus on my own, and I came across this question. I've been struggling for a couple of hours, and I'd really appreciate some help. I approach this problem using Lagrange Multipliers.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Let $f(x, y) = ax + by$ and let $g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$. Then, by lagrange multiplier method, we have

$$a = \lambda(2x) $$

and

$$b = \lambda(2y),$$

from which we get

$$\lambda = \frac{a}{2x} = \frac{b}{2y}.$$

Then, I divided the two equations and I found $x = \frac{ay}{b}$, which I plugged into the constraint equation, but I got nowhere. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations that you get are:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a=2\lambda x\\b=2\lambda y\\x^2+y^2=1.\end{array}\right.$$Assuming that $a,b\neq0$, then you get that $\lambda\neq0$, that $x=\frac a{2\lambda}$, and that $y=\frac b{2\lambda}$. So, from the third equation you get that$$\left(\frac a{2\lambda}\right)^2+\left(\frac b{2\lambda}\right)^2=1.$$From this, you get two values for $\lambda$: $\lambda=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2$. So, $(x,y)=\pm\left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$.

Now, deal with the cases $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how to relate this to $|ax + by| \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ though. Do I just plug in $(x, y)$ back in for $|ax + by|$?

Comment: Yes. It follows from what I did that the maximimum and the minimum are $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ respectively.

Comment: I plugged in your coordinate of $(x, y)$ in the positive case, and I found $|ax + by| = (a^2 + b^2)/(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2})$. What can I do from there?

Comment: I would use the fact that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

At the stationary point, when $a=2\lambda x$ and $b=2\lambda y$, we get the value to be
$$
\begin{align}
ax+by
&=2\lambda\!\left(x^2+y^2\right)\\
&=2\lambda\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Now to compute $\lambda$,
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=x^2+y^2\\
&=\left(\frac a{2\lambda}\right)^2+\left(\frac b{2\lambda}\right)^2\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
2\lambda=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\tag3
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By Cauchy Schwarz we get
$$(ax+by)^2\le (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: Is there any way to do it without Cauchy Schwartz? This is part (a) to a question, and part (b) asks to prove the Cauchy Schwartz inequality, so I'm assuming that I'm not supposed to be using it for this initial part.

Comment: You can use the Lagrange Multiplier method, but you have forgotten to differentiate with respect o $\lambda$$

Comment: Why would one differentiate with respect to $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the equations you get, you can write

$$x=\frac{a}{2\lambda}\\ y=\frac{b}{2\lambda}$$

and plug that into $$x^2+y^2=1$$

which is the equation you get differentiating wrt $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

You were actually well on your way to completing the proof.  Inserting your result into the constraint equation yields

$$ x \ = \frac{ay}{b} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \left( \frac{ay}{b} \right)^2 \ + \ y^2 \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \frac{a^2 \ + \ b^2}{b^2} \right)  y^2 \ \ = \ \ 1   $$
$$   y^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{b^2}{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ , \ \  x^2 \ \ = \ \ \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^2 · \frac{b^2}{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{a^2}{a^2 \ + \ b^2} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x \  =  \ \pm \frac{|a|}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ \ , \ \ y \  =  \ \pm \frac{|b|}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ \ , $$

as **José Carlos Santos** shows and which is presumably what you found.

The next question that arises is:  what are we to do with this result?  What you have found represents coordinates of tangent points to the unit circle for   lines represented by the function $ \ ax \ + \ by \ $ .  If we take, for instance, $ \ a > 0 \ , b > 0 \ $ (the other possible cases work similarly), then we have two lines with slope $ \ -\frac{a}{b} \ < \ 0 \ $ which contact the circle at $ \left( \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ , \ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \right) \ $ and $ \left( -\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ , \ -\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \right) \ \ . $  These points lie on the lines

$$ ax \ + \ by \ \ = \ \ a·\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ + \ b·\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{a^2 \ + \ b^2}{\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2}} \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2} $$
and $ \  \ ax \ + \ by \ \ =  \ \ -\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ . $ [the geometric interpretation of **robjohn's** result]

All of the parallel lines passing through the circle are between these two lines, so we can conclude that for all points on the circle,

$$ -\sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ \le \ \ ax \ + \ by \ \ \le \ \ \sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ | \ ax \ + \ by \ | \ \ \le \ \ \sqrt{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ . $$